# How can I get this syntax to work in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

simplest repo, how can I get this to work in Oracle?

```
SELECT 'X' NewColumn, * FROM MyTable;
```

I get

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 23

My actual issue is:

1. I'm using an ETL tool that allows automapping if I use `SELECT *`
2. I want to use `ORA_ROWSCN` to implement incremental loads

So the real query I'm running is:

```
SELECT ORA_ROWSCN, * FROM MyTable;
```

I get the same error for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is valid if you alias the table and the `*`.

```
SELECT ORA_ROWSCN, t.* FROM MyTable t;
```

No idea whether your ETL tool knows how to do that.  Of course, you could always create a view `vw_table` that runs this select and then use the view in the ETL tool.

Comment: Sweet. I knew it would be something simple. Yes the ETL tool can handle it (Azure Data Factory)